# Neo4j Beginner Delete Statement

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am learning NEo4j from last few days. I created node with Relationship from NEO4j online tutorial.

1. Create node Mystic River using Statement

   ```
   CREATE (:Movie {title:"Mystic River", released:1993})
   ```
2. Create node Kevin

   ```
   CREATE (:Person {name: "Kevin Beacon",born:1998});
   ```
3. Added Relationship

   ```
   MATCH (p:Person),(m:Movie) WHERE p.name="Kevin Beacon" and m.title="Mystic River" CREATE UNIQUE (p)-[:ACTED_IN{role:["Sean"]}]->(m) RETURN p,m;
   ```

Is there any way to rename existing relationship delete relationship between two node and create new relationship.

Alternatively I deleted node and realtionship by detach delete. and then recreated new one.

```
MATCH (n:Movie{title:"Mystic River"}) DETACH DELETE n;
```

Kindly suggest if there is rename of relationship.

Regards
Faizan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rename already existing relationship, but you can copy it and delete an old one.

Create data

```
Create (p:Person)-[r:RELATED{time:timestamp()}]->(b:Team) return *
```

Copy old relationship with new name and deleting old one.

```
Match (p:Person)-[r:RELATED]->(b:Team) 
with * Create (p)-[r2:NEW_NAME]->(b) 
set r2 = r with * 
delete r 
return p, b
```